# Django loop though unicode form input and reference tuple

Tags: python, django

I have a check box form that a user can make multiple selections from before submitting. When my view gets this input it is in unicode, and I am a little confused on the correct way to process this.

The check boxes will represent predefined tuples that i will go though depending on what is selected and submitted.

Here is a example I put together to try to figure this out,

```
>>> b = ('mike', 'fred', 'paul')
>>> g = ('sally', 'sara', 'heather')
>>>
>>> selection = [u'b']
>>> type(selection[0]) 
<type 'unicode'>
>>> for name in selection:
...     print name
...
b
>>>
```

This is closer,

```
>>> selection = [b]
>>> for name in selection:
...     print name
...
('mike', 'fred', 'paul')
```

Tried to convert the unicode to ascii but thats not working,

```
>>> for i in selection[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore'):
...     print i
...
b
>>>
```

This is how I would like to handle the form data,

```
>>> for i in b:
...     print i
...
mike
fred
paul
>>>
```

This is more of a python than Django question of how to reference a variable that contains a unicode tuple name and be able to iterate though those objects.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
b = ('mike', 'fred', 'paul')
selection = [u'b']
for name in locals()[selection[0]]:
    print name
# mike
# fred
# paul
```

Comment: That only works when I select just b, however if b and g are selected I get, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Then check type and iterate if a list.